# Fixing ArcGIS Pro crash with opening notebooks after installing Anaconda

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, windows-10, anaconda, arcgis-notebook

I have had problems with opening notebooks in ArcGIS Pro 2.5 since installing 64-bit Anaconda 3 on my PC (Windows 10 OS). When I create a project in ArcGIS Pro and try to open a notebook within project (or open Python window or Analysis tab), software fatally crashes.

I uninstalled Anaconda from my PC and hoped it would help ArcGIS Pro begin behaving normally again, but I still have same error. Based on what I've read here, it seems that some people have had success with installing a 32-bit version of Anaconda that runs concurrently on same machine as ArcGIS Pro.

Does anyone have suggestions of how I might fix ArcGIS Pro issue with opening notebooks?

Comment: You can't use a 32-bit Anaconda with 64-bit ArcGIS libraries.

Comment: @Vince that's not really a problem for me. I want to use Anaconda separately for other data science related tasks outside of ArcGIS.

Comment: @julianas An uninstall/reinstall would do the same as a repair (just takes longer) - it would fix any disconnects from files replaced or re-pointed by the Anaconda install.  I have Anaconda and ArcGIS Pro 2.5 installed on my laptop so it should work

Comment: @Midavalo do you have 64-bit version of Anaconda? I installed Anaconda first, then ArcGIS Pro. Everything was working fine, but then needed to uninstall/reinstall Anaconda for another reason. After the reinstall, ArcGIS Pro began having problems.

Comment: Actually I wonder whether your problem may be similar to an issue I had recently - See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366201/failed-to-load-system-tools-error-from-arcgis-pro-geoprocessing

Comment: @julianas Yes it's 64bit Anaconda

Comment: My point is that a 32-bit install can't possibly conflict with Pro. The joy of Windows installs is that last install wins, potentially corrupting previous installs in subtle ways. The OS in use may be a significant player in this drama, but isn't listed

Comment: @Vince Yes, it's Windows OS. I agree, the point of 32-bit install is to not conflict with Pro. Unfortunately I didn't realize there would be a conflict with ArcGIS Pro when I installed 64-bit Anaconda initially.

Comment: @Midavalo thanks for the link. The issue could possibly be related as I also have a fatal crash when opening the Analysis tab (where geoprocessing tasks are housed). I'll try to follow your solution and post an update once I've done that.

Comment: I suspect there wasn't a conflict until you removed the Python3 install that received the ArcPy install.

Comment: @Vince that makes sense as a possibility. I'm thinking that I need to leave Anaconda uninstalled and then have Pro uninstalled and reinstalled. Then if Pro is behaving normally, I can try to reinstall Anaconda at that point.

Comment: The exact Windows OS might make a difference here, which is why I suggested that you add it to the question.